# Error reading hdf file in R

Tags: r, windows, gdal

I have two hdf4 files namely *file 1*:"MYD04_L2.A2011001.2340.006.2014078044212.hdf"  and *file 2*: "MYD04_L2.A2011031.mosaic.006.AOD_550_DT_DB_Combined.hdf". First one is raw data file with 72 sub-datasets and second one is the file I obtained after ordering (i.e. post-processed). For the first R code:

```
layer_name <- getSds("MYD04_L2.A2011001.2340.006.2014078044212.hdf",method="mrt")
layer_name$SDSnames[66:68]
[1] "AOD_550_Dark_Target_Deep_Blue_Combined"
[2] "AOD_550_Dark_Target_Deep_Blue_Combined_QA_Flag"
[3] "AOD_550_Dark_Target_Deep_Blue_Combined_Algorithm_Flag"
```

It works ok with `method="gdal"` as well. However, when I try to read *file 2*, a window pops up showing `gdalinfo.exe has stopped working` (method = "gdal"). The same kind of problem arises for mrt and it shows `sdslist.exe has stopped working`. I get following error message:

> Error in sds[[i]] <- substr(sdsRaw[i], 1, 11) == "SDgetinfo: " :
>   attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex

Is single layer is the issue here? As the first one has 72 sub-data sets and second one has only one sub-data set (assuming because of the given file name as I couldn't read it), have R failed to read the data file? Can anyone propose any solution for reading such data files? If `ncdf4` package is the solution with enabled `hdf4`, can anyone explain, step-by-step, how can I enable `hdf4` and build `ncdf4` using windows platform?

Comment: What is the `mosaic.006.AOD_550_DT_DB_Combined` product? Where does one get it or how is it produced?

Comment: I received it after ordering it in NASA LA DAAC data products.

Comment: Thanks, contrary to MYD04_L2, MYD04_L2.AYYYYDDD.mosaic does not seem to be a standard product, and I could not find one in LAADS archive. Could you please update your question with an instruction on how to obtain this product.

Comment: From "search and order", I selected platform (aqua) and collection. Then I selected the required dates and tiles (for location). After that, I ordered for some pre-processing, that is, I selected two of the Sds files, ticked the option for alignment of same data file for the pre-selected location and submitted my order. I think the problem arose from the fact that the hdf file had only one layer of data rather than multiple. Therefore, it could not be read. For later orders, I selected GeoTiff formatted data and I could easily read them in R.